# Setting up a multilingual wordpress site

Tags: multilingual, wordpress

I am trying to set up a multilingual site using wordpress. I went through http://codex.wordpress.org/Multilingual_WordPress#Plugins_that_direct_you_to_external_translation_services and decided to use this option Plugins like Multisite Language Switcher and the newcomer Multilingual Press link together separate WordPress network (multisite) installations for each language by pinging back and forth..

Now i installed the Multilingual press and set up a network. The url of my site was wordpress.private.net and next on is it.wordpress.private.net. Both the domains are served from same folder. But still when i visit the it.__ site it shows in english language and that too without all the posts.

I get this error on network dashboard

**You didn't setup any blog relationships! You have to setup them first to use Multilingual Press. For this, go to Network » Sites » and choose a blog to edit. Then go to the tab "Multilingiual Press" and set up the relationships.**

But there is no option to set up the relationships in the tab "Multilingiual Press. Please guide me where am i going wrong?

Any other way to set up is also welcome.

My main moto is to run my wordpress site in two languages

Answer (score 1):

I'm also developing a website in two languages.

I haven't used what you are using, so I cannot help you in that regard.

For my project I installed [qTranslate plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/qtranslate/) and I haven't had any problems with it so far.

In the plugin settings you specify language you want to use and other settings like how the language will appear in URL (?lang=en , /en/ in front of URL , http://en.yoursite.com)

When you edit post or page, you will have additional tab in the editor, one for each language, so it is really easy to use it.

It also supports qTranslate Services, that ables you to use professional human translation services with a few clicks, but I haven't used that yet.

Comment: but wont it increase the work of author since he would have to post in both language. Also if he dosent know both languages then?

Comment: Plugin does have an option "Hide Content which is not available for the selected language.", but I haven't use that since in my case every page needs to be translated in both languages.

Comment: Also you don't post twice (once for each langage). All the languages are stored into a single post.

Answer (score 0):

A general note:
Do NOT auto translate your pages with Google Translate. This is basically spamming the google index.
If you want to autotranslate your page, use the google translate widget.
You can read that somewhere in the google guidelines too.

About your plugins:
qTranslate is fine and simple. But it does store all translations into one post. So if you later decide to change to a different plugin, you are toast.

I've heard about Multilingual, but I think it might still be a bit unstable.

The most commonly used is WPML. Might not be the best and it's not free. But it works and I have many clients that use it happily.

But again, DON'T auto translate your page. It's useless and will get you down ranked.